How do you interpret this data about corporate bonds?
If I have a corporate bond portfolio that has the following relative to the benchmark (this was given to me as interview question):
Given an initial portfolio with the following statistics (as of yesterday): short bucket (+29bps), the mid bucket (+15bps) and the long bucket (-8bps). Where + means overweight and - means underweight. And the overall portfolio Spread relative benchmark is 17bps
And the market/index as of yesterday are 5/10 credit curve (flattened), 5/30 credit curve (steepeened) and 10/30 credit curve (steepened).
How would I interpret this data in terms of the following question:
Interprete the current portfolio and what is positioned for.

What do you do if you expect growth to increase and spread to tightened
What to do if you expect economy growth to decrease and spread widen
What sector do you expect will outperform and underform given you economy expectations


This reads a lot like a problem set question...

i polished it a little better in the form of a problem set. But it was a conversation with the interview.

Based on the given data, you are quite bullish on the short-term bonds, moderately bullish on the medium-term bonds, and bearish on the longer time duration bonds.
Since the portfolio spread is wider than that of the market by 17bps, you expect it to modestly outperform the benchmark.
Flattening of the 5/10 curve indicates 5 year bonds interest rates to increase with respect to 10 year bond rates.
Steepening of the 5/30 and 10/30 curves indicates greater long term rate increases over the short and medium term respectively.
The way your portfolio is positioned as of now is for:
i. Providing protection against rising short-term rates
ii. Minimizing exposure to increase in long term rates
iii. Generating more fixed income from short and medium-term holdings
Interpretations:

What do you do if you expect growth to increase and spreads to tighten?

Increase in growth leads to higher interest rates but lower credit risks, thus causing spreads to tighten.
You can consider reducing the weightage of the short bucket and increasing that of the long bucket, to capture potential gains as a result of the spread tightening.

What to do if you expect economy growth to decrease and spreads to widen?

This would be the exact reverse of the previous case.
You would want to rebalance the protfolio and have more holdings in the safer short-term bonds, and offload the riskier long term bonds.

What sector/s do you expect would out-perform and under-perform given your economy expectations?

If growth increases, sectors that normally show out-performance are tech and consumer discretionary.
In case of reduced growth, consumer staples and utilities normally perform better.
These are of course, simplistic answers to simplistically framed questions.
The nuances would for sure matter.
Hope this helps :D

thanks a lot, and your comment did really help to get a full understanding of the questions asked. I think I got high growth lower spread. But on summarizing the initial portfolio I was wrong. Thanks for the explanation.
